# Batchjob for changing the date format in a filename

Tags: batch-file, filenames

hope somebody can help me.

I need a .bat doing the following:

- Run in folder "A" all the time
- waiting for a file to appear in the following format:
  1_33530_Jim_Hutchinson_m_**23**.**04**.**1965**_20210628-163636_D-Endo14.pdf
- reformatting the file to
  1_33530_Jim_Hutchinson_m_**19650423**_20210628-163636_D-Endo14.pdf
- write the new file to folder B

Meaning in the filename the date format should change from DD.MM.YYYY to YYYYMMDD everything else
before and after should be untouched

How can I do that with a looping batch job?

Kind regards and thanks in advance
Sven

Comment: There are hundreds of questions and answers posted under the [[tag:batch-file]] tag, which split strings using specific characters. You could isolate the date of birth portion splitting with underscores, then change the date of birth order splitting that isolated string using periods. You need to make more effort and attempt the task yourself by adapting one or more of the methods from your search results. There is a search box at the top of each page of this site. Please also take the [tour], and read through the linked pages of [ask], before you [edit] your question to include a [mcve].

Answer (score 0):

Split filename 1_33530_Jim_Hutchinson_m_23.04.1965_20210628-163636_D-Endo14.pdf to three part. Delimiter is point.

Using string substitute split 1_33530_Jim_Hutchinson_m_23 to 1_33530_Jim_Hutchinson_m_ and 23

```
set filename1=!temp_var1:~0,-2!
set day=!temp_var1:~-2!
```

Using string substitute split 1965_20210628-163636_D-Endo14 to 1965 and _20210628-163636_D-Endo14

```
set year=!temp_var2:~0,4!
set filename2=!temp_var2:~4!
```

Make new filename

```
set new_filename=!filename1!!year!!month!!day!!filename2!.pdf
```

full code

```
setlocal ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION
for %%f in (*.pdf) do (
  for /f "delims=. tokens=1,2,3" %%a in ("%%f") do (
    

    set temp_var1=%%a
    set month=%%b
    set temp_var2=%%c

    set filename1=!temp_var1:~0,-2!
    set day=!temp_var1:~-2!
    set year=!temp_var2:~0,4!
    set filename2=!temp_var2:~4!

    set new_filename=!filename1!!year!!month!!day!!filename2!.pdf

    copy %%f B\!new_filename!
  )
)
```

Comment: clever (ab)use of the name format. You can avoid re-applying the extension by changing `tokens=1,2,3` to `tokens=1,2,*` (where `*` = "take all the rest without further tokenizing")